# How to find filebytes of individual uploaded files in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, file, file-upload

I am implementing the multiple file upload through asp.net fileupload control & saving uploaded files to database. While iterating the files, I am trying to set the Data property of File class. For single file, I can set it as File.Data = postedFile.FileBytes.
But, while iterating files, FileBytes property value getting set everytime similar.
Can anybody explain what could be the reason? How can I implement it?

code sample:

```
 if (fuAttachment.HasFiles)
   {
        foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in fuAttachment.PostedFiles)
        {
            DataAccess.File file = new DataAccess.File();
            file.Data = fuAttachment.FileBytes;//not working for multiple files.
        }
   }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be reading the contents of the file from `postedFile`?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, a file upload control still posts files behind the scenes.

here is basically how to retrieve multiple files, this works with one and/or multiple file upload controls, and counts **ALL** the posted files in **ALL** of the upload controls:

```
HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];
    try
    {
        if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
           //do stuff with your file, check the attributes and functions of 'userPostedFile' to see what you can get from it, there is an input stream as well as file name among everything else.
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
         //here do stuff if file upload fails, adjust exception type as needed.
    }
}
```